# Print parameter value if it exists for all class methods

Tags: python, parameters

I have a class I wrote where a majority (but not all) of its methods take in an int parameter `foo`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def fun_one(self, foo: int):
        pass

    def fun_two(self, foo: int, flu: int):
        pass

    def fun_three(self, flu: str, foo: int):
        pass

    def fun_four(self):
        pass
```

Is there any way I can make my program log the values of `foo` whenever they come in in any of the methods without needing to manually go to every relevant function and add `print(foo)`?

Also important to note, sometimes `None` will be passed as a parameter to these functions. There needs to be a distinction between functions which simply don't have the parameter and functions where the parameter's value is `None`.

The easiest solution I can think of is using regex to find every instance of `def … foo … :`, then adding a line break and print statement after each line, but I'm trying to see if there's a built-in, nicer way I can do this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you already tried? My first thought is to write a decorator for the class that uses introspection to find methods with a `foo` parameter; have you considered that?

Comment: Nothing like this exists. Take `fun_one` for example. The *function* has no association with the class at all; `MyClass.fun_one` just happens to be a reference to the function produced by the `def` statement as a side effect of where the `def` statement occurs. The class has no "hook" into the internal workings of the function.

Comment: @wjandrea I haven't tried anything yet, as I didn't know where to start. I'll look into that and see if that's a possibility! The only problem is that I still have to type it manually everywhere, but since I can collapse functions, this would probably be easier.

Comment: Why would it matter if the value could be `None`? Whatever does this has to test whether the variable name exists, not what its value is (if it doesn't exist, it can't even get the value).

Comment: @Barmar Because I don't know how this would be implemented, so I just wanted to specify that. That way, in case there's some function `get_parameter_value(foo)` and it returns `None` if the parameter doesn't exist, I didn't want that to be confused with a `None` value passed as a parameter. Looks like you figured that out [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74482372/10442089) :)

Comment: Add the Python Zen teaches, explicit is better than implicit. You should explicitly implement logging in each of those methods. It may be reasonable to implement the logging as a decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to every method:

```
if 'foo' in locals():
    print(foo)
```

Comment: This is better than the `print()` I was planning on using, but I'm trying to find out how to simulate adding this to every method without pasting it over and over in every function in my editor.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But this way you don't have to add something only to the appropriate methods, you can add it to all of them. That could be done at once with an editor command.

Answer (score 0):

As a note to people in the future, I ended up using a regex script to do this. In VS Code's find/replace, I used the following:

- Search: `(def.*foo: int.*\n)`
- Replace: `$1        print(foo)\n`

(I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but I'll leave that to the regex experts)

This changes the script to the following:

```py
class MyClass:
    def fun_one(self, foo: int):
        print(foo)
        pass

    def fun_two(self, foo: int, flu: int):
        print(foo)
        pass

    def fun_three(self, flu: str, foo: int):
        print(foo)
        pass

    def fun_four(self):
        pass
```

Comment: I won't mark this as a solution just in case someone comes along with an actual solution. I consider this more of a hacky workaround than an actual solution.